# Vanishing of one-half of Fourier coefficients implies boundary of $H^p$-space function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hardy-spaces

Let $p\in [1, \infty]$.
Suppose $g \in L^p(T)$ where $T$ is the unit circle.

I want to prove g is boundary value of $f \in H^p$ if and only if $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(e^{it})e^{-int} dt = 0$ for all $n \in \{-1, -2, \cdots \}$.

I can prove one direction ($\Rightarrow$): Since $f \in H^p$, so it is a Poisson integral of boundary value. Therefore $f(z) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} P_r(\theta - t)g(e^{it}) dt$ where $P_r(\theta - t) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} r^{|n|}e^{in\theta}e^{-int}$ and $z = re^{i\theta}$. Therefore, $f(z) = \sum r^{|n|}e^{in\theta}\int g(e^{it})e^{-int}dt = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{g}(n)z^n$ where $\hat{g}(n)$ is the $n$th Fourier coefficient. Since $f$ is holomorphic, therefore the negative Fourier coefficients are zero.

Can anybody help me to prove the other direction? I have no clear idea to prove it.

Comment: I think the converse implication is nontrivial. For $g$ you define $f(z)=\sum,_{n=0}^\infty \widehat{g}(n)z^n$   for $|z|<1.$ Then $f(z)\to g(z_0),$ where $|z_0|=1$ when $z\to z_0,$ $|z|<1,$ nontangentially.

Comment: For the other direction, you simply need to check the holomorphicity, since the bound on the $L^p$ norm of $f_r$ comes for free: $\|f_r\|_{L^p}=\|g*P_r\|_{L^p}\le \|g\|_p$.

Comment: BTW, depending on the results you have seen so far, the case $p=1$ might be a bit trickier, since some approaches require to use the F&M Riesz theorem for that (or use this result to prove that theorem)